# Load data in div from external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Info.html

```
var Element = function ( id, w, h, position, rotation ) {
var html = [
  '<div class="wrapper"  width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '"  >',
  '<ul class="stage clearfix">',
  '<li class="scene" id="' + id + '">',
  '<div class="movie i1" id="attacker"  >'
  '<div class="poster">',
  '</div>',
  '<div class="info" url-data="' + id + '">',
  '</div>',
  '</div>',
  '</li>',
  '</ul>',
  '</div>'
].join('\n');
var div = document.createElement('div');
$(div).html(html);
}

function init() {
var group = new THREE.Group();
var str = {"0":'http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html'

}

for ( var i = 0; i < totalSpheres; i ++ ) {
  var xp = centerX + Math.sin(startRadians) * circleRadius;
  var zp = centerZ + Math.cos(startRadians) * circleRadius;
  group.add( new Element( str[i], 1000, 1000, new THREE.Vector3(xp, 0, zp), new THREE.Vector3(0, i*incrementAngle * (Math.PI/180.0), 0) ) );
  startRadians += incrementRadians;
  particles.push(group);

}
scene.add(group);


});
```

I want to load data dynamically to this div with class info from a file content.html So I tried using url-data attribute but the problem is neither the console shows any error nor it shows the data. I know that I can directly put the data in div but the problem is that the data keeps on changing as the id change.
Here is my content.html from which I am trying to load the data into class div.
Content.html

```
<header>
<h1>It's a Wonderful Life</h1>
<span class="year">1946</span>
<span class="rating">PG</span>
<span class="duration">130 minutes</span>
</header>
<p>
In Bedford Falls, New York on Christmas Eve, George Bailey is deeply troubled. Prayers for his well-being from friends and family reach Heaven. 
Clarence Odbody, Angel Second Class, is assigned to visit Earth to save 
George, thereby earning his wings. Franklin and Joseph, the head angels, 
review George's life with Clarence.
</p>
```

I want to put the data in content.html directly into class info.

Comment: AJAX is exactly what you need, sir.

Comment: I have at least 20 pages to load and writing the ajax code for every page will be a repetitive job that why I have done this. I have also tried to load the data in iframe b this method and that worked fine but loading data in div doesn't work.

Comment: Create one page that does the work, stores the results, and distributes data. Then have the 20 pages point to that page via iframe (iframe can be a 1x1px square.) Then at each "satellite" page, you call on the main page. The main page creates the data and the "satellite" page can use `importNode()`.

Comment: Why would you need to write AJAX specifically for every page? Writing code frees you from repetitive tasks if you write your code to handle data generically. Use arrays and make IDs work for you and if that's not possible, use another hook like tag or class.

Comment: I have used ajax and achieved what i wanted but the problem occurs when loading the data in different div. how can i pass dynamic id to div @zer00ne

Comment: Store the ids in an array then distribute the ids by indices. Accessing an array's elements doesn't require ids if you refer by index.

Comment: did you see that var str line in my code. thats what i am doing there but that isin't working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733887/same-div-filled-with-data-instead-of-different-divs

Comment: Your `str` is an `object literal` containing one `{property (key)`  : and one `value`}. If you made `str` into an array: `var str = []` instead of an object `var str = {}`, you can populate said array with multiple objects: `str = [{ID0:url3}, {ID1:url4},{ID2:url5}]`

Comment: I achieved the same with object literal only. I used Object.Keys to obtain the keys and put it into the dynamic id

Comment: Great, since you resolved your own issue, you should answer your own question.

Comment: okay, i will. thanks for the help. Please upvote it if you find that I did it the right way

Comment: I most certainly will, sir, happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change var str to:

```
var str = {
                "attacker":$.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
    success: function (data) {      
                console.log(data);
        $("#attacker").append(data)
   }}),
                "defender":$.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/defender.html",
    success: function (data) {      
                console.log(data);
        $("#defender").append(data)
  }}),

                "goalkeeper" : $.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
    success: function (data) {      
                console.log(data);
        $("#goalkeeper").append(data)
   }}),
                  "midfielder":$.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/midfielder.html",
    success: function (data) {      
                console.log(data);
        $("#midfielder").append(data)
  }})


             }

        var allKeys = Object.keys(str);   // obtain keys
```

pass both keys and value to he element function:

```
group.add( new Element( allKeys[i], str[i], new THREE.Vector3(xp, 0, zp), new THREE.Vector3(0, i*incrementAngle * (Math.PI/180.0), 0) ) );
```