# Same div filled with data instead of different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function(){ 
    var camera, renderer;
    var mpi=Math.PI /180;
    var circleRadius = 1800;
    var startAngle = 0;
    var centerX = 0;
    var centerZ = 0;
    var startRadians = startAngle + mpi;
    var totalSpheres = 5;
    var incrementAngle = 360/totalSpheres;
    var incrementRadians = incrementAngle * mpi;
 var Element = function ( id, w, h, position, rotation ) {
      var html = [
        '<div class="wrapper" >',
        '<ul class="stage clearfix">',
        '<li class="scene" >',
              '<div class="movie i1" id="' + id + '" >',
           
               '</div>',
                  '</li>',
                                 '</ul>',
         '</div>'
       ].join('\n');
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      $(div).html(html);
     
      var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( div );
      object.position.x = position.x;
      object.position.y = position.y;
      object.position.z = position.z;
      object.rotation.x = rotation.x;
      object.rotation.y = rotation.y;
      object.rotation.z = rotation.z;
      return object;
     
      }   
   init();
      function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
    var renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight*.85);
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10 );
    camera.position.set(-100,60,4000);
    var group = new THREE.Group();
    
                var str = {"0": $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/pages/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#id").append(data);
     }}),
     "1":$.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/pages/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#attacker").append(data);
     }}),
     "2":$.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/pages/content.html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#attacker").append(data);
     }})

    
    }


    for ( var i = 0; i < totalSpheres; i ++ ) {
                    var xp = centerX + Math.sin(startRadians) * circleRadius;
     var zp = centerZ + Math.cos(startRadians) * circleRadius;
                    group.add( new Element( str, 1000, 1000, new THREE.Vector3(xp, 0, zp), new THREE.Vector3(0, i*incrementAngle * (Math.PI/180.0), 0) ) );
     startRadians += incrementRadians;
     

      }
        scene.add(group);

       
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    
   }
   
    });
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
 background: #fbc73b;
 font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
 max-width: 960px;
}

.stage {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
}

/*************************************
Build the scene and rotate on hover
**************************************/

.scene {
 width: 260px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 30px;
 float: left;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
 -moz-perspective: 1000px;
 perspective: 1000px;
}

.movie {
 width: 260px;
 height: 400px;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(-130px);
 -moz-transform: translateZ(-130px);
 transform: translateZ(-130px);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 350ms;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 350ms;
 transition: transform 350ms;
}

.movie:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-78deg) translateZ(20px);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(-78deg) translateZ(20px);
 transform: rotateY(-78deg) translateZ(20px);
}

/*************************************
Transform and style the two planes
**************************************/

.movie .poster, 
.movie .info {
 position: absolute;
 width: 260px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #fff;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.movie .poster  {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(130px);
 -moz-transform: translateZ(130px);
 transform: translateZ(130px);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.movie .info {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(130px);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(130px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(130px);
 border: 1px solid #B8B5B5;
 font-size: 0.75em;
}

/*************************************
Shadow beneath the 3D object
**************************************/

.csstransforms3d .movie::after {
 content: '';
 width: 260px;
 height: 260px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 30px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(130px);
 -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(130px);
 transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(130px);
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 350ms;
 -moz-transition: box-shadow 350ms;
 transition: box-shadow 350ms;
}

.csstransforms3d .movie:hover::after {
 box-shadow: 20px -5px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/*************************************
Movie information
**************************************/

.info header {
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 195px;
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.info header h1 {
 margin: 0 0 2px;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

.info header .rating {
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 padding: 0px 3px;
}

.info p {
 padding: 1.2em 1.4em;
 margin: 2px 0 0;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #666;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 border-top: 10px solid #555;
}

/*************************************
Generate "lighting" using box shadows
**************************************/

.movie .poster,
.movie .info,
.movie .info header {
 -webkit-transition: box-shadow 350ms;
 -moz-transition: box-shadow 350ms;
 transition: box-shadow 350ms;
}

.csstransforms3d .movie .poster {
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 40px rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.csstransforms3d .movie:hover .poster {
 box-shadow: inset 300px 0px 40px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.csstransforms3d .movie .info, 
.csstransforms3d .movie .info header {
 box-shadow: inset -300px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.csstransforms3d .movie:hover .info, 
.csstransforms3d .movie:hover .info header {
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

/*************************************
Posters and still images
**************************************/

.scene:nth-child(1) .movie .poster {
  background-image: url(../img/withoutblur.jpg);
     background-size: 260px 400px;
  
     
     
    
}

.scene:nth-child(2) .poster {
  background-image: url(../img/triangulated-image.jpg);
    background-size: 260px 400px;
  
}

.scene:nth-child(3) .poster {
  background-image: url(../img/defender.jpg);
     background-size: 260px 400px;
  
   

}
.scene:nth-child(4) .poster {
  background-image: url(../img/defender.jpg);
    background-size: 260px 400px;
  
}


.scene:nth-child(1) .info header {
 background-image: url(../img/triangulated.png);
  
}

.scene:nth-child(2) .info header {
 background-image: url(../img/triangulamage.png);
}

.scene:nth-child(3) .info header {
 background-image: url(../img/defend.png);
}
.scene:nth-child(4) .info header {
 background-image: url(../img/defend.png);
}

/*************************************
Fallback
**************************************/
.no-csstransforms3d .movie .poster, 
.no-csstransforms3d .movie .info {
 position: relative;
}

/*************************************
Media Queries
**************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 60.75em){
 .scene {
  float: none;
  margin: 80px auto 80px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I have this script in which I made a structure for a div and I want to add data to it dynamically. Everything is fine except everytime div is filled with same data instead of different data. I wanted to give them dynamic ids.

I made 3 divs and added data with different url but everytime data is showing in same div instead of differnt divs.

Comment: heck this line  str[i] , str should be simple array!

Comment: I want to add all the divs to a sphere  that's why I wrote that

Comment: If is a possible insert code snippet

Comment: added a code snippet @NikolaLukic